# Dropdown Menu on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im totaly new to Javascript and i fell so lost. Have done a little HTMl/CSS but no JS. Can some1 tell what I need to do in JS to make my Code work? :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Uppgift 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="button-dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">
            Mandagens Lunch <span>#</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Carbonara
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Pizza
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Köttbullar Med Mos
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reasons, we are unable to debug images...

Comment: Please provide your code as code... if you cant do it here for "some reasons", do it here: http://codepen.io/

Comment: what is the actual result that you are trying to achieve? Clicking on the <a> toggle the dropdown-menu? Are you willing to use jquery? How difficult is to search on google: how to make a dropdown menu in js?

Comment: When I post the Code it shows up as the actual result of the code and not the Code itself, how do I fix that?

Comment: The one and only comment can be "Ensure menu.js available in the same directory where your html file resides"

Comment: @Hippimaster Add 4 spaces of indentation before each line. Clicking on the `{}` icon will do this for you automatically. Or, alternatively, use the JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet tool, which will provide a JSFiddle-like UI to insert your code.

Comment: @Hippimaster https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#link-code

Comment: @Hippimaster note that we have to take a look at your menu.css and menu.js too... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here i've build something from scratch.. isn't beatiful, but it works.

JS:

```
var dropdownHidden = true;
function toggleDropdown(){
  if(dropdownHidden){
    document.getElementById('dropdown-menu').style.display = '';
    dropdownHidden = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('dropdown-menu').style.display = 'none';
    dropdownHidden = true;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="button-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" onClick="toggleDropdown()">
            Mandagens Lunch <span>#</span>
        </a>
        <ul id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu" style="display: none">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Carbonara
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Pizza
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    Köttbullar Med Mos
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

> Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgpdYO

Note: this is a "you havn't provided any code solution"